# PowerShell - Delete a print queue from a print server

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, wmi, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2003

I have a printer server which hosts around 1000 printers. I want to delete one of these.

I am currently using this command:

```
$p = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_printer -ComputerName $server -namespace "root\CIMV2" -filter "name='printer0456'"
```

It works, it finds the printer, and then I can use this command to delete it:

```
$p.delete()
```

But what freaks the hell out of me, is that it takes like 2-3 minutes for the first command to find the printer. To me, it makes to sense at all.

Is there something I am doing wrong, or something else I can use to delete a printer faster ?

**EDIT: check my response**

That way, it only fetch until it founds the correct printer, instead of parsing the whole printer list.

Comment: When using the `Get-WmiObject` command remotely, it can take a while for there to be a return.  It get's the whole list and filters before it returns anything, so it can take a while, especially since you have about 1000 printers for it to filter through.  If you want to speed things up, you can try to use the PowerShell remoting and invoke the command as though it was local.  I haven't used that feature to much, so I can't say if it will speed up or not, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TEMPORARY SOLUTION I HAVE FOUND**

```
$p = $null
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_printer -ComputerName $server|ForEach-Object{
    if($_.name -eq "printer0456"){
        $p = $_
        break
    }
}
if($p -ne $null){
    $p.delete()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use a WMI accelerator to speed up a lot your query against WMI.

```
$PrinterInstance = [wmi]"\\$CentralServer\root\cimv2:Win32_Printer.DeviceID='$PrinterName'"
```

DeviceID is an indexed value in the WMI Database and by default DeviceID should be the same as the printer name.

Answer (score 1):

Its the WMI query that costs, so cache the results. Pull all the printers in a collection. Filter the collection and delete the printers you wish to.

```
$printers = gwmi Win32_printer -ComputerName $server -namespace "root\CIMV2"

$del = $printers | ? { $_.Name -eq "printer1"}
$del.delete()
$del = $printers | ? { $_.Name -eq "printer6"}
$del.delete()
$del = $printers | ? { $_.Name -eq "printer89"}
$del.delete()
```

You can use `-like` and `-match` to filter printers with similar enough names. Like so,

```
$printers = gwmi Win32_printer -ComputerName $server -namespace "root\CIMV2"

$del = $printers | ? { $_.Name -match "printer10[1-3]" } # Match printer101..103
$del | % {$_.delete()}
```

Comment: This doesnt help me, as I am only deleting 1 printer per script instance. I have described a solution in my post.

Answer (score 0):

`$p = gwmi win32_printer | ? {$_.name -match "PrintServer"} | % ($i in $p) {$i.delete()}`

This will only remove printers that have the following print server name in their name path.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `gwmi win32_printer | ? {$_.name -match "PrintServer"} | % ($i in $_) {$i.delete()}`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$PrintersTodelete = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_printer -ComputerName $server -filter "name='printer0456'"
 if($printersToDelete){
     Foreach($printer in $PrintersTodelete){
         $printer.delete()
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<#
    Delete printers on remote servers using csv list(server,printer)
    Note: For queues with job(s), they will be stuck in a "deleting"
    state and you must clear the job(s) manually, the queue will delete
    after that. Or, you will need to write in code to stop spooler and
    delete jobs from \spool\printers. Not a big enough deal to warrant
    risk of spooler not starting back up.
#>

$InCSVPath = "\\path_to_list_file\printerstodelete.csv"

$csv = Import-Csv $InCSVPath
foreach($item in $csv){ 

       $server = $item.Server

       $printer = $item.Printer 

       $a = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_printer -ComputerName $server -Filter "name= '$printer'"

        if($a){

             "Deleting Printer: " + $a.Name #

              $a.Delete()

         }

         else{

               "could not delete: "+$printer

         }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone's going down the PowerShell path unnecessarily because gathering a collection of installed print queues on a print server that could have 2000+ queues installed is slow. Extremely slow.

Microsoft has a few built in printing management scripts, typically having a default path of: c:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US

Want to delete 1 print queue named "Q1"? Run this from a command prompt:

cscript c:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs -d -p "ap1"

Gets the job done, satisfies the op's how-to question & is blazing fast (<1 second) compared to running PowerShell to make WMI calls (>2 minutes with 3400 queues installed). Build the formula, save the column to a batch file & run it. Takes care of all of the other proposed answers a lot more efficiently

It's also super simple to build the commands in Excel for deleting multiples as a cleanup effort of some sort

Side note-- Use correct terminology: A "printer" is the physical device spitting out paper. Windows has "print queues" installed, not "printers"